# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger2

Добрый день, разбираюсь с библиотекой dagger2 и не могу понять где у меня ошибка, извиняюсь если вопрос простой, но не смог пока найти ответа. 
Ошибка такая:

```
    Error:(12, 10) error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
android.content.Context is injected at
com.example.pashko00710.cyberplattest.ui.recyclerview.NewsAdapter.<init>(context, …)
com.example.pashko00710.cyberplattest.ui.recyclerview.NewsAdapter is injected at
com.example.pashko00710.cyberplattest.ui.MainActivity.newsAdapter
com.example.pashko00710.cyberplattest.ui.MainActivity is injected at
com.example.pashko00710.cyberplattest.injection.components.ActivityComponent.inject(mainActivity)
```

Код компонентов:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    @ApplicationContext
    Context context();

    Application application();

    ActivityComponent addActivityComponent(ActivityModule activityModule);

    DbHelper providesDbHelper();

    DataManager providesDataManager();

    void inject(LoadNewsService loadNewsService);
}


@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

Код модулей:

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {
    private Activity activity;

    public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides @NonNull
    Activity providesActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides @NonNull
    @ActivityContext
    Context providesContext() {
        return activity;
    }
}


@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final Application application;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @NonNull
    Application providesApplication() {return application;}

    @Provides @NonNull
    @ApplicationContext
    Context providesContext() {return application;}
}
```

Код qualifier:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityContext {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApplicationContext {
}
```

И scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PerActivity {
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно какие у вас scoup'ы. В компоненте вы указываете PerActivity в модуле ActivityContext [Это](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/04/11/tasting-dagger-2-on-android/) читали?

Comment: @YuraIvanov , добавил описание, scope  у меня только PerActivity.